# How to schedule data pipe line in different time zones(other than UTC)?

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

We have to configure a service where it will consider daylight saving. I am trying to use expression(inTimeZone) in data pipeline schedule object to call the service according to CST timings but could not find solution. Could anyone please suggest on this.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling in a different timezone is currently not supported by Data Pipeline. However, if you need to use runtime fields like @scheduledStartTime or @actualStartTime as part of your activities you can use Data Pipeline date expressions to convert to any timezone. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-reference-functions-datetime.html